# Install Package Error

Tags: lightning, package-install, flexipages

> Could not find entity [ApiAnomalyEventStore]
>
> Employee: Component [flexipage:filterListCard] attribute [entityName]:
> Could not find entity [ApiAnomalyEventStore]

I am trying to install a package and the above error is received, but not much luck in figuring this one out. Not sure if I need to add to the package or make some changes in sandbox I am trying to install package in.

Comment: Are you the package owner or have you reached out to whoever owns the package?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_apianomalyeventstore.htm):

> Special Access Rules
>
> Accessing this object requires either the Salesforce Shield or Event Monitoring add-on subscription and the View Real-Time Event Monitoring Data user permission.

As such you need to ensure that you have had one of these add-ons activated on the target org before installing this package.

If this seems inappropriate you need to contact the managed package developer to discuss this dependency.